# Ubuntu 19.10 fail to connect to mysql

Tags: mysql, 19.10

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 19.10. MySQL works fine. MysqlWorkbench works fine.

I have a Java program that runs in Eclipse. But the program doesn't work anymore. I get this error message:

> can't connect to mysql

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be because the upgraded version of MySQL is incompatible with older versions of the java connector library.  I managed to fix the problem by upgrading the Java depencency:

```
     <dependency>
       <groupId>mysql</groupId>
       <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
-      <version>5.1.30</version>
+      <version>5.1.48</version>
     </dependency>
```